# Lightning Network Nodes do not report Bolt9 Features

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, ln-gossip

Looking at the output of the [describeGraph](https://api.lightning.community/api/lnd/lightning/describe-graph/index.html) command of my node (LND), I have seen that my node detects approximately 19,000 nodes. Of those 19 thousand, 6 thousand do not report any bolt9 feature.

```
lnd@node:~$ lncli describegraph | grep -c "features"            
18969
lnd@node:~$ lncli describegraph | grep -A 1 "features" | grep -c }
6274
```

Is there any logical reason why this could happen? I thought it was mandatory to report the features that are implemented in order to use the protocol correctly.

Comment: Could it be that those 6 thousand nodes are running older versions and might not support certain features or report them correctly? or some nodes might be using non-compliant implementations that don't report BOLT #9 features at all?

Comment: @deyw It could be, at first I thought of nodes that work with smartphones. It remains to be seen even if these nodes are really useful for the network. Because if they are not, the LN numbers are far worse than they might first appear.